# Why can't I record PvZGW?

Tags: recording, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I decided to record some PvZGW the other day with Bandicam.  My problem I that no window shows up to record on Bandicam even when I select the game multiple times.  I have tried restarting Bandicam as well as the game but that doesn't seem to help.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen with other games?  Or just PvZ:GW?

Comment: Just pvzgw not any other ones.

Comment: Launch BandiCam as admin

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no window shows up to record"?

Comment: The window that is recording on Bandicam says "0x0 ()"

Comment: Not to detour from the actual issue, but have you tried using other programs? I would suggest OBS, I've never had issues with it recording anything off of my screen.

Comment: @stay (late, but this is relevant) I've had issues with OBS as well, particularly on Alien: Isolation.  I finally had to ask some friends who do this sort of thing and they recommended XSplit.  Of course, they had a code for a free month of it, so I'm not sure if the free version would work or not.